# MySQL: Replace string in mediumtext

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb, regexp-replace

I have a table with an entry of type `mediumtext`. This entry contains encoded website content with 40k+ chars like this: `<!-- {"type":"layout","children":[{"type":"section","props":{"style":"default","width":"default","vertical_align":"middle","title_position":"top-left","title_rotation":"left","title_breakpoint":"xl"...`

In the text there is the following span: `...<span id=\""myDate\"">26.05.2020<\/span>...`

I would like to replace the date inside the span with my `REGEXP_REPLACE`-function which works when I use text:

```sql
UPDATE `jl72a_content` SET `fulltext` = REGEXP_REPLACE( 
    '...<span id=\""myDate\"">26.05.2020<\/span>...',
    '<span id=\"myDate\">(.*?)\\\/span>',
    '<span id=\"myDate\">my new value<\/span>')
WHERE id = 2;
```

But I have the problem that I can't use the `fulltext` as the string:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp SELECT `fulltext` FROM `jl72a_content` WHERE id = 2; 
UPDATE `jl72a_content` SET `fulltext` = REGEXP_REPLACE( 
    (SELECT `fulltext` FROM temp WHERE 1),
    '<span id=\"myDate\">(.*?)\\\/span>', 
    '<span id=\"myDate\">my new value<\/span>?')
WHERE id = 2;
```

I can't cast the result of the temporary table as a `mediumtext` and `varchar` is limited to 65,535.

How can I replace the span in this entry?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Please don't try to parse html with regex

Comment: I can't imagine an other option to edit a value from that template framework without using the component. 
I have a batch script which uploads key figures files to a dashboard. The corresponding date should be updated automatically.
Otherwise I have to write a content plugin which loads the date from an separate (new) data table.

Comment: I have now solved it with a content plugin.